# resharper disabling intellisense

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, intellisense

For some reason, resharper often disables intellisense.  It usually happens when a red box appears around what I'm typing, what that is for I have no idea.  Any ideas of what I can try?

[image]

Comment: That looks like you're stuck within the rename refactoring. If that's the case, you should make sure to confirm the renaming first. A second possibility is while using live templates. Is that the case?

Comment: I don't really know what live templates are. All I'm doing is typing away and the red box sometimes comes up, sometimes not.  Of those times the red box appears, intellisense gets disabled about half the time.